# Modal window causing alignment issues (possibly due to OnePageScroll.js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, plugins, alignment

**SOLUTION:**
All I had to do was change section-center alignment that was causing page overflow.

**Problem**
When I open the modal windows *(overlaying window, like what sites use to ask you to sign up for a newsletter before you leave)* on the first page, they all work just fine. When I scroll down and open a modal window on the second or third page, it breaks the alignment of elements behind the modal window.

**Pics**
[image: Working]
[image: Broken]
As you can see in the first picture, it works just fine on the first page. The issue occurs on pages two and three, and it appears to be something happening to the alignment of the background elements.

**Relevant Code**
*My HTML:*

```
<!-- Modal window -->
<div id="open-csci-modal" class="modal-bg">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">
    <img src="img/exit-icon.png"></a>
    <h2>Computer Science Major</h2>
    <p>Paragraph about what I've learned in school.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

*My CSS:*

```
section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
}
.modal-bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modal-bg:target {
  opacity:1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modal-bg > div {
  width: 800px;
  height: 410px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: rgba(112, 156, 250, 0.75);
}
```

**Links**
[OnePageScroll.js source code (GitHub repo)](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll)
[My portfolio source code in its entirety (GitHub repo)](https://github.com/GitMazzone/portfolio)

Thanks so much in advance. I've been struggling to find the cause of this for some time now.

Comment: Trace styles in chrome dev tools on the broken page.  You can see which stylesheets contain the offending styles, and how to overwrite them.  If the offending styles are inline then you'll need to look into the javascript.

Comment: It's probably because I'm relatively new to this but... I don't really know what I'm looking for. I only have two stylesheets - mine, and the one for the OnePageScroll.js.